# removing question marks alone

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove with PHP question marks in excess or that do not belong to a question, like from this:

```
question? ???? ???
question???
```

to this: (keeping only one question mark )

```
question?
question?
```

this is my code:

```
$text = 'question? ???? ???
question???';
echo preg_replace("?", "", $text);
```

Comment: What constitutes "excess"? If we're just keeping the last question mark of every line, how do the spaces in between get removed? There are a couple gaps in your explanation that could be filled different ways -- be more specific.

Comment: You really should look at some regex tutorials before trying to use it...

Comment: just want to keep one question mark at the end of the sentence! excluding any other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace('/\?[? ]+/', '?', $text);`

This will replace a question mark followed by any combination of question marks and spaces with a single question mark.

Comment: How so? Check it out: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b54d2dc6c2303817510104dba435f7e47b66a733

Comment: Of course it wont modify it in place. If you want `$test` to be the new resulting string you will have to reasign it `$test = preg_replace('/\?[? ]+/', '?', $text);`